# Is there any way to disable, or at least bypass the rate limit for a bot in discord?

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently came across a [gambling bot](https://top.gg/bot/395385545326592010) that simulates the action of slot machines by **editing a bulk message in a fast rate**. I tried simulating this with the code below:

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    description='0'
)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
for i in range(20):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=f'{i+1}'
    )
    await msg.edit(embed=embed)
    asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

The code above, as a simulant of what I want to replicate, takes a short break every 5 edits, destroying the construction of my idea. Since it is possible, as seen from the [gambling bot](https://top.gg/bot/395385545326592010) itself, what do I have to do in order for my bot to perform unhindered?

Comment: Ratelimits exist to protect discord's backend from being hammered. IF you could just disable/bypass them they wouldn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, the rate limit is there for a reason. Going against it breaks the Terms of Service, and there's really no way to get around that. If there was, why would Discord have the limit in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(
    description='0'
)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
for i in range(20):
    if i%5 == 0:

        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f'{i+1}'
        )
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```